# Inventory Management System Issue

Tags: c#, client, inventory, stock

I need to resolve this problem in an application that i develop for iventory management the problem is if the application is running in tow computers in the same time and users ordered the same product in the same time and there are only 1 product in the sock as quantity .. the programme accept the order ! .. how i can detect that the product is orded by the first user in oderhand do not change the quantity of the stock until the user confirme the list of commands

by the way i use sql server as database

Comment: DbConcurency - > https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171936.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have two columns "orderPlaced" and "orderconfirmed" in the "order" table.
Update it as soon as order placed/confirmed. This is simple way.

Comment: i think that the problem will still even i implement this idea .. the problem is what if the two or many users ordered in the same time the same product ? did you understand me

Comment: first come first serve. For the first request, turn on the "orderPlaced" on "orderconfirmed - no" aganist the product. From there onwards any number requtests, use both fields and keep them on hold, Till "orderconfirmed - yes". If order is declined turn off "orderPlaced - no". Make it available for next customer. You can use "Queue" data structure to maintain ... first come first serve.

Comment: Pavan Chadaka , i hop if you give me an exemple of an implementation to more understand the proposition that you give me .. thank you

Answer (score 0):

for this problem you can simply do is you can update the products_Table in the database instantly 
for example : as soon as you add the product to the checkout list update the product table quantity this will solve your problem

Comment: i can't change the quantity of the stock instantly.. what if the user cancel the operation , and what if the computer sutdown when the system change the quantity and the user dosent confirm the order list ?